# @Timed on quarkus reactive endpoint is not giving the correct response time

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-reactive

Below is my endpoint.

```
    @Path("/data")
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Timed("rest.request.timer")
    public Multi<***> getData(***) {
        \\ app logic
    return x;
    }
```

Micrometer by default times the HTTP requests and http_server_requests_seconds_sum is giving the right value for how long it takes to respond to a request.

I have added custom metric on the method with @Timed annotation, I am expecting the value of this metric to be same as that of `http_server_requests_seconds_sum` , but they are not same.

I have also tried recording the time taken without annotation like below , still the values are not same. Any clue why they not same ?

````
Timer timer = Timer.builder("rest.request.timer").register(Metrics.globalRegistry);

public Uni<***> getData(* request) throws IOException 
{ 
   return this.timer.record(()-> {
            return serviceObject.get();
        });
 } 

    ```
````

Comment: @Timed with a Multi return type is not really going to work. What are you trying to measure?

Comment: Basically I want to measure the time taken to complete the request.

I want to add a tag say "id" to metric to distinguish between the requests.

Comment: But a multi might not complete, it could be an infinite stream

Comment: Hi geo , I have modified the return type to Uni and trying to time the requests in the below way , still the metric not giving the correct value.


public Uni<***> getData(* request) throws IOException {

        long start = Instant.now().toEpochMilli();
        // app logic
        long end = Instant.now().toEpochMilli()-start;
        this.timer.record(end,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        return x;
    }

Comment: Metric is registered as Timer.builder("request.timer").tag("id","req1").register(Metrics.globalRegistry);

Comment: Please update the description of the issue with the new code as it is impossible to read code in comments

Comment: updated , pls look at the second block of code

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would do something like:

Timer timer = Timer.builder("rest.request.timer").register(Metrics.globalRegistry);

```
public Uni<***> getData(* request) throws IOException 
{ 
   long start = Instant.now().toEpochMilli(); 
   // app logic 
   return x.invoke(() -> {
       long end = Instant.now().toEpochMilli()-start; 
       this.timer.record(end,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
   });
 }
```

Comment: tried by passing the business logic into the timer to record the execution time, metric didnt give the right value , pls check the updated code block , is this the suggested approach ?